# Firefox addon code for every tab open

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm attaching some functionality to javascript by doing a firefox addon. However when coding in chrome and listening to the load event in the chrome overlay triggers for every loaded tab, but the "content" variable only points to the tab currently in the foreground.

How can I get the content of every tab upon document load from a firefox addon?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are [using code like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) to be told every time a new page loads (which is what you really want to use if you aren't), `aEvent.originalTarget` is a reference to the document that the event was for.